# Mongodb vs Cassandra for aggregating, searching and analyzing many logs

Tags: mongodb, logging, cassandra, database

I'm working on a project that does log aggregation and analytics as part of a bigger project. I don't know which database to choose for handling these logs. Lately I'm going back and forth between MongoDB and Cassandra, but I'm sure there are others that fit my needs as well. Which one should I choose and why?

The whole thing is quite at the beginning right now, but here are the requirements so far:

- logs are in the syslog format
- queries are mostly on a small string that's now in the message, but I will get it on a separate field. And there will also be filters based on date, severity or tag. Very rarely, people would just search for a random string within the message.
- hourly analytics from some of the log entries
- keep the logs for a configurable amount of time
- more will come, I'm sure :) That's why I'm thinking NoSQL is more appropriate, because we can change the schema.

We are expecting to grow the database to some TB of data (and ~50K inserts per second), so sharding is a must. Queries are not so often, because they are mainly used by the developers of the bigger project. But a result needs to be returned in a few seconds.

Right now, the storage is common (and slow) for all the machines. So for scalability, I suppose we need to make best use of memory and multithreading - in order for sharding to make sense.

The basic ideas I got so far is that MongoDB has more features, such as regex or sorting results, and it's easier setup to a decent configuration, while Cassandra seems more scalable (by simply adding servers), and also has a few neat features, like putting a TTL on data.

Comment: I've ended up using Elasticsearch. Take a look here for some more info: [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2012/05/19/elasticsearch-for-logging.html)

Answer (score 5):

Sparsely columnar datastores such as Apache Cassandra are excellent at aggregating time series data. See the following articles for examples:

- [Basic time series with Cassandra](http://rubyscale.com/blog/2011/03/06/basic-time-series-with-cassandra/)
- [4 Months with Cassandra](https://www.cloudkick.com/blog/2010/mar/02/4_months_with_cassandra/)
- [Understanding the Cassandra data model](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/ddl/index)

Comment: Are you talking about the fact that Cassandra automatically stores a timestamp for each column? At first I thought this is really useful for me, but then I realized that I actually need a different timestamp: the one when the event is generated on the server, not when the event got to the log aggregator. If you think I'm missing something here, can you please write in some details?

Comment: I'm referring specifically to the data modeling approach. Cassandra's concept of timestamp has nothing to do with this. Please read the above articles - they will provide some insight into how you would structure column families for storing log data.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB does sound like a good fit for your requirements. Here's why:

- indices: since you want to run occasional queries, it's nice not to have to maintain them in your app or have a separate search app (Lucene).
- scales well (built-in sharding support, replication)
- writes are asynchronous (by default, you could make them synchr.), that is non-blocking, and fast. You might lose few in certain failure scenarios, but for logs and analytics, it wouldn't make a difference.
- fairly powerful query API (not like relational, no joins, but better than all other nosql key-value stores, and sounds more powerful than what Cassandra offers).

You might even find a proper configuration to have it in a non-sharded setup. For example by default it syncs to disk every 60sec, which means 60secs of writes will be buffered hence reducing IO. I've tried it on a half a terabyte of data on a single machine and a single indexed field queries run in cca 100-200ms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It fits with what I have in mind right now, which is to go with MongoDB and then maybe switch to something else only if I run into problems.